# If Condition Fits, Remove 58th (or Last) Character

Tags: regex, perl, sed

The following is a part of a very large file:

```
 AX1       -0.7766512832    0.5148273234    4.2786094015 >
            1.7946619816    0.7753532457    1.8759964126    0.3364947702 >
            0.9685478959    0.3507513619    0.3894364805    0.7390333869 >
            0.3061019863
 AX9       -2.4577177384   -0.4989707852   -1.3388532333 >
            2.1316147211    0.6123791026    2.7070013136    0.4139841780 >
           -0.1511381820    0.3962115748    0.2241446997   -0.4274101066 >
            0.4097737023
 AX20      -1.9584498342   -0.3207285057    0.5492832625 >
            5.8330021421    0.6706829149    2.3033089678    0.5822925912 >
            2.6239469531    0.5245128606    0.8995560125    1.4869098981 >
            0.0473609746
```

I have to delete the > character at the end of the line which starts with the pattern ' AX' (whitespace+AX). I can recognize two patterns here: 1. If line starts with ' AX', then remove the last character; or 2. If the 58th character in a line is '>', then delete that '>'. So that it looks like:

```
 AX1       -0.7766512832    0.5148273234    4.2786094015
            1.7946619816    0.7753532457    1.8759964126    0.3364947702 >
            0.9685478959    0.3507513619    0.3894364805    0.7390333869 >
            0.3061019863
 AX9       -2.4577177384   -0.4989707852   -1.3388532333
            2.1316147211    0.6123791026    2.7070013136    0.4139841780 >
           -0.1511381820    0.3962115748    0.2241446997   -0.4274101066 >
            0.4097737023
 AX20      -1.9584498342   -0.3207285057    0.5492832625
            5.8330021421    0.6706829149    2.3033089678    0.5822925912 >
            2.6239469531    0.5245128606    0.8995560125    1.4869098981 >
            0.0473609746
```

Can you help me with a sed or perl one-liner that does the job? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Perl One-Liner

```
perl -pe 's/^ AX.*\K>$//mg' yourfile
```

For safety, I didn't give you the option to replace it directly in the file so you can test it first. However, if you want to replace the contents of the file directly, use `-i -pe`, or, to make a backup:

```
perl -i'.bak' -pe 's/^ AX.*\K>$//mg' yourfile
```

**Explanation**

- The `m` flag turns on multi-line mode, allowing `^` and `$` to match on each line
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `AX` matches literals
- `.*` gets us to the end of the line
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- The `>` matches the character you want to replace
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain this in short as well? Thanks again!

Comment: One minor suggestion: I had to add a . next to the ^ anchor to make sure that the whitespace is read as well. Works well. Thanks a lot!